# overloading over function types with templates

Tags: c++

There is a common abstraction for both containers and functions. I learned it in Haskell, and I'm trying to implement it in C++.

Most C++ programmers are familiar with std::transform, roughly speaking given a function from type A to B, you can convert a container of type A to a container of type B.

You can transform functions in a similar way, given a function foo from A to B, you can convert a function bar taking Z to A to a function foo . bar taking Z to B. The implementation is simple, it's just composition.

I wanted to define a function fmap, on containers and functions, to reflect this abstraction for generic programming.

The container was easy (I know this isn't fully general)

```
template <typename A, typename Func>
auto fmap(Func f, vector<A> in) {
  vector<decltype(f(in[0]))> out_terms{};
  for(auto vec : in)
    out_terms.push_back(f(vec));
  return out_terms;
}
```

However, the analogous function for functions makes me much more nervous.

```
template <typename FuncT, typename Func>
auto fmap(FuncT f, Func in) {
  return [f, in](auto x){
    return f(in(x));
  };
}
```

Although the template won't specialize for anything except callable things, I'm worried this will confuse overload resolution. I would like to introduce type constraints on the template parameters to restrict their resolution to function types to keep the name space clean. And I was going to ask how to do that.

This abstraction is extremely general, there are corresponding fmaps for pointers to values, which I suspect might conflict as well.

So I think my question is, can I have two different template implementations with the same template level signature? I'm almost certain the answer is no but maybe something similar can be faked. And if not, what tools are available today to distinguish between the overloads? Especially for function types.

This seems, to me, to be a textbook case for concepts, though I'm not sure.

Edit: Boost would be acceptable to use, and SFINAE in particular. I'm trying to find a solution that would be familiar to most programmers, and as convenient, and canonical as possible. I could rename fmap to compose, but then the programmer would have to know to pass compose to a template function accepting fmap. That would be unfortunate, because fmap is semantically unique.

Edit 2: A trivial example of how this is used.

```
template <typename T>
auto double_everything(T in){
  auto doublef = [](auto x){return 2*x;};
  return fmap(doublef, in);
}
```

It generalizes maps over containers to maps over "container like" things. So `double_everything(vector<int> {1, 2, 3})` returns a vector with its elements doubled. But `double_everything([](int x){ return x + 1; })` returns a function whose outputs are twice the outputs of the increment function. Which is like doubling a kind of list. The abstraction has some nice properties, I'm not just making it up. At any rate, renaming the function `fmap` to compose doesn't answer the question.

Edit 3:
`fmap` for a template `C` takes functions from `A` to `B` to functions from `C<A>` to `C<B>` and satisfies `fmap( compose(f, g) , c ) = fmap( f, fmap( g, c ))`. This is a nice structure preserving property.

Functions which do this for ranges already exist by different names. But ranges aren't the only templates on types. Here is `fmap` for `std::optional`:

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
auto fmap(Func f, optional<T> o) -> optional<f(*o)>{
  if(o)
    return f(*o);
  else
    {};
}
```

This implementation doesn't involve any range concepts at all, like the`fmap` for functions presented earlier. But it satisfies the semantic requirements for `fmap`.

I'm trying to define `fmap` for different overloads in the same way I would define a new `operator *` for a custom matrix type. So I would happily define `fmap` in terms of `boost::transform_iterator`. Then these algorithms would work with a function generic in terms of `fmap`.

Here is an example of such a function:

```
template < 
  template<typename, typename> class Cont, 
  typename Fmappable, 
  typename Alloc, 
  typename Func>
auto map_one_deep(Func f, Cont<Fmappable, Alloc> c){
  auto g = [f](Fmappable x){ return fmap(f, x); };
  return fmap(g, c);
}
```

now if we write

```
auto lists = vector<vector<int> > { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
auto lists_squared = map_one_deep( [](int x){return x*x;} , lists);
```

`lists_squared` printed gives

```
1 4 9
16 25 36
```

If we instead had a vector of optionals, the optionals would be squared provided they contained elements.

I'm trying to understand how one should work with higher order functions in c++.

Comment: Pretty sure this is impossible to do in the general case. I would just rename your function `compose`.

Comment: I no longer know enough C++ to assess this post, but I think it is at least relevant to what you are trying to do: [The Functor Pattern in C++](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2012/07/the-functor-pattern-in-c)

Comment: You may restrict your template type for your function with SFINAE.

Comment: Are you sure you need SFINAE? There probably does exist a scenario where it's ambiguous to the compiler, but [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/456cf695144fad06) seems to work fine.

Comment: @AndyG To clarify my nervousness. fmap should be defined for each type it's used on, because very different types have very different implementations. Functions have a specific implementation different from containers or trees, but I'm stuck using a fully generic interface. 

This may not be a problem. It just makes me nervous. I don't know if I need SFINAE.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "fmap should be defined for each type it's used on" At first glance it sounds like overloading for those types specifically would be the best approach, but I presume you mean something else.

Comment: @AndyG Like operator +. The implementation for integers is different then for matrices. So they should get their own +. I implemented + for integers (vectors), and then I went to implement it for matrices (functions), and found I needed to make this second + fully generic. Which makes me nervous.

Comment: @Polymer: Honestly you should be okay. Since you implemented it already with some specific types, they'll already be better matches than the fully generic one. That is, the fully generic one will be called as a last resort, which sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: @AndyG That may be true, maybe I'll just use static_asserts to warn users about semantics. Do you think users would prefer that to function_traits?

Comment: As a side note, in vector overload you already know the size of the result, so instantiating the returned value of known size and filling it instead of appending to the end saves you a few reallocations.

Comment: I am a bit skeptical about your attempt to use C++ like Haskell. Why don't you stick with C++ idioms, like ranges, transforms, etc.?

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin I have no problem with `std::transform`. If I need an algorithm which traverses a list I'll thumb through the stl. `fmap` is meaningful for `unique_ptr`, and functions, as well. Iterators don't interface with these.

Comment: There is boost::indirect_iterator for containers of pointers, or universal boost::transform_iterator which is what you try to reinvent as `fmap`.

Comment: Also see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin I edited the question. Is it more clear what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Essentially, you would like to implement a domain specific language in C++ that resembles Haskell. Why not just use Haskell?

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin Can you explain why you think that's what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @Polymer That is what you said: _I learned it in Haskell, and I'm trying to implement it in C++._

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin After reading your comment, I tried to rewrite the answer only using references to transform. Introduced overloads like `unique_ptr<double> o= transform( unique_ptr<int>{2}, [](int x){return to<double(x)>*1.5;})` would compose with ranges. But some of Eric Niebler's proposed transform functions accept containers while returning pairs of integers. That breaks the above generic examples I gave because c++ doesn't overload over return values. Introducing a new name solves this. It's just a more general transform, but I can't call it that.

Comment: `unique_ptr<int>{2}` is not well-formed C++.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin Guess I don't know what I'm talking about then. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Well, do not feel down. Imagine someone coming to Haskell forum and asking them how to use Haskell like C++. The primary question is why?

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin C++ is the most powerful pragmatic language I have ever worked with. I have yet to find an abstraction it can't make usable. The generic example I gave using `fmap` works in C++, but it doesn't work in rust, C#, or Java. Yet C++'s performance is generally faster and easier to understand, certainly much easier to understand then Haskell's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the simplest compromise I found

```
template <typename FuncT, typename O, typename T>
auto fmap(FuncT f, function<O(T)> in){
  return [f, in](T x){
    return f(in(x));
  };
}
```

Unfortunately this requires that `function<Output(Input)>` decorate the call site, and it litters indirections. <s>I'm pretty sure this is the best one can do if constraining `fmap` is required.</s>

Edit: [You can do better.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40166486/730606) The link gives a way to restrict to callables, that also in-lines.

The function could be written like this:

```
template <typename FuncT, typename T>
auto fmap(FuncT f, tagged_lambda<T> in){
  return tag_lambda([f, in](T x){
    return f(in(x));
  });
}
```

You could choose the version you want at the call site, by calling

`fmap(g, tag_lambda({}(int x){return x + 1;}) );`

or

`fmap(g, function<int(int)>({}(int x){return x + 1;}) );`

Given how templates work, I'm pretty sure tagging the function is required.

Here is a blog post which also talks about the issue, and discusses other options.
http://yapb-soc.blogspot.com/2012/10/fmap-in-c.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can fake it with SFINAE, but you shouldn't. It's a matter of style and idiom.

Haskell is all about type classes, with a programmer expecting to have to spangle each type with all the clubs it belongs to. C++, in contrast, wants to be more implicit in specifying a type's capabilities. You've shown "`vector`" and "arbitrary callable" there, but why just `vector`? Why not an arbitrary container type? And this arbitrary container type I just wrote has an `operator()`, because reasons. So which one should it choose?

Bottom line, while you can use SFINAE tricks to resolve technical ambiguities, you shouldn't use them to resolve essential ambiguities. Just use two different names.

Comment: `vector` seems to be a premature optimization. To mimic Haskel it should be a `list`.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin `vector` and `list` are isomorphic, but vector generally performs better on processors. Because c++ doesn't implement `list` as an algebraic data type, it isn't as safe as Haskell's `list`. So using it by default wouldn't buy you anything. I'm not trying to mimic haskell, I'm trying to use the abstractions I've learned from it.