# Defining interfaces for functions that only accept functions

Tags: c++, c++11

Define (f + g) to mean (f + g)(x) := f(x) + g(x). Conventional matrix addition is consistent with this definition.

Here is a naive implementation

```
template<typename Funcf, typename Funcg>
auto operator+(Funcf f, Funcg g){
  return [f, g](auto x){return f(x) + g(x);};
}
```

This fails because `operator+` only consumes user defined types. The next attempt gives

```
template<typename R, typename I>
auto operator+(std::function<R(I)> f, std::function<R(I)> g){
  return [f, g](auto x){return f(x) + g(x);};
}
```

This works and it doesn't litter the namespace. However it litters indirections, and the call-site is ugly `auto added = std::function<int(int)>{f} + std::function<int(int)>{g};`.

If the first `operator+` was allowed(or was renamed to add), the call site would be nicer, and the functions would be inlined. But it attempts to match against everything, which seems brittle.

Is it possible to define a template interface that specifies the inputs are functions, still inlines them, but doesn't pollute the namespace with an overly generic name?

In other words, is there a compile time version of `std::function` with a more convenient call site? I strongly suspect the answer is no. And if the answer is no, is there a compromise between the above two extremes?

Or option three, am I thinking about this the wrong way? How would you model (f + g) in c++?

Comment: How about `f +arg_wise+ g`?

Comment: Personal opinion: Even if you got that to work, it would be abuse of operator overloading. This behavior is far from canonical.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen Functions form a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_vector_spaces#Function_spaces). The behavior is fine because ((f + g) + h) = (f + (g + h)) and (f + g) = (g + f).

Comment: @Yakk can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: @Polymer Functions *mapping between the same two sets* form a vector space. That's not true in general.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen Doesn't my second template function satisfy that requirement?

Comment: @Polymer Only if both functions operate on the entire set of possible values if the data type `I` (or on the same subset), which is far from clear in general. (Yeah, you could define the sum to operate on the intersection of both ranges of definition, but again, it is not obvious that some `operator +` does that. Just give it a name.)

Comment: @Polymer: Look at named operator.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen Assume the input functions are required to be polynomials. And that I'm trying to use generic functions which assume the types operated on have `operator+`. Regardless, this question isn't about whether this use of `operator+` makes sense. It's about trying to write an overloaded function against functions, not the entire namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operators only works for user defined types. Then let's make your function be!

We can define a type that is basically a lambda, but with a user defined type name:

```
template<typename F>
struct addable_lambda_impl : F {
    template<typename T>
    addable_lambda_impl(T f) : F{std::move(f)} {}

    using F::operator();
};

template<typename F>
addable_lambda_impl<F> addable_lambda(F f) {
    return addable_lambda_impl<F>{std::move(f)};
}
```

This is a class that will extends any type and will use it's `operator()` function.

Now, you can use the `addable_lambda` function:

```
auto lambda = addable_lambda([](){});
```

Implementing your operator is easier too:

```
template<typename F, typename G>
auto operator+(addable_lambda_impl<F> f, addable_lambda_impl<G> g){
  return addable_lambda([f, g](auto x){ return f(x) + g(x); });
}
```

It's not perfect, but slightly less ugly. Plus, you don't suffers the overhead that `std::function` adds.

Comment: You may even return `addable_lambda` to allow `f + g + h`.

Comment: This is really cool. It's more clever then I would like, but It does what I asked. I doubt there is a good way to get around decorating functions.